# Versioning: shall I commit non-working code (separate branch)?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, versioning, cvs

Sorry I wasn't able to decide whether this question belongs to stackoverflow or not, here it is.

I was wondering if it should be a good idea or not to commit frequently, even if in my case would mean submitting non-working code.

I am refactoring a whole application to change to a new library, and I'm worried if I do not commit frequently.

I have a separate branch to work on the feature to avoid breaking the code on master (using Git).

Can you provide better solutions, and possibly some examples why this would be good/bad and, if there are, alternatives?

Comment: You can commit as much as you like locally while it's not working, just don't push it up to the main repo. Then when your work is complete you could use rebase to compress several commits into one to tidy things up before you push to the main repo.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119784/is-it-good-idea-to-require-to-commit-only-working-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My usual workflow is: I commit a lot of non-working code onto a branch that can clearly be identified as such, e.g., a branch `tmp/bart/working-on-feature-X`. I also push it a lot to the remote (where basically, I am using the remote as a backup).

Whenever my code is in a good (publishable) state, I rebase: squashing all commits that belong togheter into one commit with a meaningful message, push to a new branch on the remote and create a pull request

Comment: Yeah I usually have a team repo, which I fork and branch on my own github account. There is where I would put non-working code

Comment: But I am not experienced enough to rebase, I haven't actually learned about rebasing in the first place.